# Using authentication only one time passwords

Tags: passwords, authentication, one-time-password

I would be interested in advice.
Imagine a authentication mechanism where users are authenticated ONLY using
some code (e.g., one time password) which they receive (say as SMS) on their mobile phone?

Is it secure? I think it is not a good practice to rely authentication only
on such codes which come on mobile phone, because someone can just
steal your mobile phone and that's it.

I think better alternative would be to **combine** the above mechanism with a username/password
authentication. What is your opinion? What are the best practices in such direction?

Comment: I think it fully depends on the use case, the threat model and attack scenarios. It apparently has enough security for many promotions where you get a unique number hidden with a product. Is it enough for online money transactions? Probably not.

Comment: This is called two-factor authentication, many services (incl google, facebook, etc) use this today.

Comment: @JimL if you regard the phone to be something you *have* then it is two factor authentication - but the line between one-factor and two-factor are a bit blurred here; if I retrieve the one time password (e.g. by listening in on the GSM network) then it becomes something you know - leaving only a single factor...

Comment: I think the way it is now, it is one factor authentication - because if someone steals your phone, he can authenticate as I mentioned using the code he receives on SMS ...

Comment: @owlstead in practice a combination of password+text message is often used by banks for micro transactions up to about 250 USD.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say just a code on the phone is weaker than username and password (because you can loose a phone and someone might abuse it). Combining them is a form of multi-factor authentication:

- something you know (password and username)
- something you have (phone with text message)

and depending on the level of authentication you need, this is considered a good and strong form of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Out of band  One Time Passcode designs like this are typically called **multiple single factors** and are quite common, especially where privilege escalation is required when the user is already logged on, e.g. making a transaction.

Mobile phones are just always-connected small computers nowadays and thus aren't a second factor - so I don't consider any of the following authentication methods as "second factor":

- bluetooth auth (is supported by some unlock screen saver functionality)
- SMS one time passcode
- NFC (used for micro financial transactions)

Multiple Single Factor **can be** stronger than single factor, although take care because asking a user for 2 text passwords isn't much stronger than a single factor password request.